# How to save R object from C API

Tags: c++, c, r

I need to save a R expression to a file, essentially

```
save( x, file="myfile.Rdata")
```

however, I need to do it from C/C++ API (since the value of 'x' is evaluated by a C++ function, that's loaded as a plugin to R). After researching the question on the net, and not finding anything useful, I went digging to the code, and figured out that there is a function "do_save" in src/main/saveload.c

```
SEXP attribute_hidden do_save(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
```

that's the .Internal that does all the work when I type "save" in R, but apparently I can't link the resulting plugin properly against R, I get the error message:

```
> dyn.load( "Plugin.so" )
Error in dyn.load("new-plugin/Plugin.so") :
  unable to load shared object 'Plugin.so':
  Plugin.so: undefined symbol: _Z7do_saveP7SEXPRECS0_S0_S0_
```

Generally speaking, how is one supposed to use these internal functions in C API, or in other words, how is one supposed to evaluate a build-in R function from the C API?

Comment: This is not a good question, a good question is "Why do you want to do that?"

Comment: "Why" is a complex explanation that would take way too much space/time. Let's just assume that it's really necessary.

Comment: You should not need to do this, so why is the only relevant question. If you [read this](http://xyproblem.info) then you might come up with the appropriate question.

Comment: Iharob Al Asimi: respectfully, don't tell me what I need and what I don't need to do. If you think it's a stupid question and/or don't want to help for any other reason, that's fine, just ignore the question and move on with your life.

Comment: I did not say it was a stupid question, read the link and see what I mean. I want to help, but you have a bad attitude. Smart people are often wrong, not so smart people are never wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a c++ function, the function name in the binary file gets changed or "*mangled*" to allow function overloading to work. To avoid that, you can use `extern "C"`, if you are not really using any c++ specific syntax or feature then use a c compiler.

For the first fix, it would go like this,

```
extern "C" SEXP attribute_hidden do_save(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env);
```

The second possible fix, is to rename your source file to have the *.c* extensions and compile with a c compiler, if it's not c++ code it will compile and you will not need `extern "C"`.

Comment: Much appreciated; thank you. 'extern' didn't solve the problem, since 'do_save' is apparently "hidden" from user (although I'm not sure how).

Comment: @Bojan, compilers can make som symbols "*invisible*". I don't know the details, but in principle they can. For instance on Windows, you need to explicitly export symbols.

Answer (score 0):

What about just constructing the R call to be evaluated at the C level, and going from there? E.g. something like:

```
SEXP mySave(SEXP object, SEXP path) {
    SEXP call = PROTECT(Rf_lang3(Rf_install("saveRDS"), object, path);
    SEXP result = Rf_eval(call, R_GlobalEnv);
    UNPROTECT(1);
}
```

(replace `R_GlobalEnv` with a more appropriate evaluation environment as needed)

The other possibility is using the `R_Serialize()` and `R_Unserialize()` APIs, but those seem somewhat more low-level than the actual R-level `save` APIs.